# How do I use CALayer renderInContext and keep the perspective transform?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

How do I use `CALayer renderInContext` and have the perspective transform `(m34)` of the layer preserved? It seems like this method assumes an Identity transform. I have tried things like transforming the context, and this is fine for translation, rotation and scaling, but there does not seem to be a way to keep the perspective of the 3D transform.

Maybe a better way to put this question: How do I apply a perspective while drawing to a CGContextRef?

Comment: `renderInContext` just draws a flattened "snapshot" of the layer. What are you expecting / hoping to do?

Comment: what happens when you render the parent layer?

Comment: @nielsbot No transform is applied unless I manually apply it to the context

Comment: @nielsbot I am looking for a way for the full layer.transform to be applied when I call renderInContext

Comment: yes--I am wondering if you can try calling renderInContext: on the parent layer instead. the transform property is how a layer is rendered in it's parent, not how it renders its contents.

Comment: Calling on parent layer still ignores transform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the method `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` which is offered since iOS 7.0. Applying the method to the view containing the CALayers will keep their 3D transformations.

Sample code:

```
BOOL opaqueBackground = YES;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theViewContainingYourCALayers.bounds.size, !opaqueBackground, 0);
[theViewContainingYourCALayers drawViewHierarchyInRect:theViewContainingYourCALayers.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
[UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

As matt pointed out, relying solely on `renderInContext:` is not possible since it disregards any transformation other than affine ones.

Late answer but I hope it still helps.

Comment: I am already using this on iOS 7+, my problem is iOS 6. I don't think it's possible on iOS 6.

Comment: I agree, I don't think so, either.

Comment: now that iOS 6 is long since been ditched by me, your answer is correct :)